# Why are some past participles listed in dictionaries as a single word, while others are not?

Tags: word-difference, dictionaries

My question is when a past participle can be thought of as a single word, not a inflectional form of verbs?

Comment: What do you mean by "thought of as a single word"?  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the participles can (and often do) have meanings of their own, as nouns or adjectives.

Comment: Especially, if their meanings differ slightly. E.g. *colored* means *having a certain color*, but not necessarily *having been colored* (and still dripping wet paint). They could also have been derived independently.